# Substitute values in Scheme lists

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, racket, substitution

Suppose I have an arbitrary list representing Boolean expressions:

`'(a and (b or c))` and another list of pairs representing the values of the literals

`'((a . #t) (b . #f) (c . #t)))`

What I want to do is replace the values in the first list using the values from the second list, and return a new list:

`'(#t and (#f or #t))`

So for example this code takes a list and an association list, and successfully replaces the values inside of it, though I'm trying to do the same thing given a list of conses instead of an association list. It works for `'(a b)  '((a 1) (b 2)) -> '(1 2)`, but I want to instead use `'((a . 1) (b . 2))`. Here is that code:

```
(define replace
    (lambda (ls a-list)
     (map (lambda (x)
            (let ((lookup (assq x a-list)))
              (if lookup
                  (cadr lookup)
                  x)))
          ls)))
```

Would anyone know how to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using assq to associate the values but still to no avail.. I'm quite new to Scheme and the syntax is tricking me.

Comment: the literal answer to your question is yes. but there are many ways to do that, I'm sure. if you'd show us any piece of code you've written we'd be able to help you with _your_ way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(define bool '(a and (b or c)))
(define pairs '((a . #t) (b . #f) (c . #t)))

(define (value-for-key lst key)
  (cond ((empty? lst) 'none)
        ((eq? key (caar lst))
         (cdar lst))
        (#t (value-for-key (cdr lst) key))))

(define (replace-bool lst vals)
  (cond ((empty? lst) lst)
        ((pair? (car lst)) (cons (replace-bool (car lst) vals)
                                 (replace-bool (cdr lst) vals)))
        (#t (let ((val-for-key (value-for-key vals (car lst))))
                (if (not (eq? val-for-key 'none))
                    (cons val-for-key (replace-bool (cdr lst) vals))
                    (cons (car lst) (replace-bool (cdr lst) vals)))))))

(replace-bool bool pairs)
```

-> (#t and (#f or #t))

First function is for searching in list of pairs key-value and returns value for given key or 'none, if that key isn't in that list.
Second function goes through Boolean expression list. Each atomic element is searched in key-value list and if it's found, is replaced. If Boolean expression contains nested expressions, they are traversed recursively.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here seems to be that a solution is needed which works on nested input lists. To that end, a `map-nested` procedure can be written. Here is a procedure which is like a simplified version of the usual `map` procedure, but that works on nested lists:

```
(define (map-nested proc xss)
  (if (null? xss)
      '()
      (let ((xs (car xss)))
        (if (pair? xs)
            (cons (map-nested proc xs)
                  (map-nested proc (cdr xss)))
            (cons (proc xs)
                  (map-nested proc (cdr xss)))))))
```

One way in which this differs from the usual `map` is that `map-nested` only takes one list as input; a typical `map` procedure takes an arbitrary number of lists which can be mapped over.

The above implementation of `map-nested` is not tail-recursive, and this could be a problem for large, deeply nested lists. It is not too much trouble to rewrite this so that it is an iterative (tail-recursive) procedure:

```
(define (map-nested proc xss)
  (let iter ((xss xss)
             (result '()))
    (if (null? xss)
        (reverse result)
        (let ((xs (car xss)))
          (if (pair? xs)
              (iter (cdr xss)
                    (cons (map-nested proc xs) result))
              (iter (cdr xss)
                    (cons (proc xs) result)))))))
```

Here `result` is an accumulator that keeps track of the results to be returned, freeing recursive calls from the need to keep stack frames. Note that `result` must be reversed before it is returned since elements from the input are consed onto the front of `result`, starting from the front of the input list. A [named let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html?q=named%20let#%28part._.Named_let%29) form is used here; this is a convenient way to set up local procedures within another function which works in both Scheme and Racket.

To finish solving OP's problem, we need only make use of `map-nested`; either of the above versions will work:

```
;;; `substs` is an a-list of the form `((a . x) (b . y) ...)`
(define (replace-elts xss substs)
  (map-nested (lambda (x)
                (let ((subst-pair (assoc x substs)))
                  (if subst-pair        ; subst-pair is #f if x is not found
                      (cdr subst-pair)  ; otherwise, subst-pair is a dotted pair
                      x)))
              xss))
```

Here, `map-nested` takes care of handling the input list, whether or not it is nested. The procedure given to `proc` is responsible for finding a substitution in `substs`, which is assumed to be an association list composed of *dotted pairs*. If proper lists of two elements are desired instead of dotted pairs, the `cdr` can simply be changed to `cadr`. When `subst` does not provide a substitution for a value from the input `xss`, that value is left unchanged.

There are a number of ways that `replace-elts` could be changed to be more or less convenient, depending on the actual conditions of use.

Sample interactions:

```
nested-map.rkt> (replace-elts '(a (b (c d) e))
                              '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (d . 4) (e . 5)))
'(1 (2 (3 4) 5))

nested-map.rkt> (replace-elts '(a (b (c d) e))
                              '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3) (d . 4)))
'(1 (2 (3 4) e))

nested-map.rkt> (replace-elts '(a and (b or c))
                              '((a . #t) (b . #f) (c . #t)))
'(#t and (#f or #t))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Common Lisp function, [`sublis`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sublis.htm), that does exactly this, but it, like other CL functions that work on tree structures of cons cells instead of straight lists, never made its way into the Scheme world:

```lisp
* (sublis '((a . t) (b . nil) (c . t)) '(a and (b or c)))
(T AND (NIL OR T))
```

A while back I wrote Racket implementations of a number of Common Lisp functions, including this one.

```lisp
(define (sublis alist tree #:test [test eqv?] #:key [key identity])
  (cond
    ((assoc (key tree) alist test) => cdr)
    ((pair? tree)
     (let ([new-car (sublis alist (car tree) #:test test #:key key)]
           [new-cdr (sublis alist (cdr tree) #:test test #:key key)])
       (if (and (eqv? (car tree) new-car)
                (eqv? (cdr tree) new-cdr))
           tree
           (cons new-car new-cdr))))
    (else tree)))
```

Example:

```lisp
> (sublis '((a . #t) (b . #f) (c . #t)) '(a and (b or c)))
'(#t and (#f or #t))
```